# Error running Zurb foundation example in learn rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm working my way through Dan Kehoe's book 2 and everything was going well until I tried to run the Zurb Foundation example.  Using Foundation 5 I get the error   ".column" failed to @extend ".small-6".
The selector ".small-6" was not found.
Use "@extend .small-6 !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.

It seems as though I have not loaded something which defines the foundation css entities, but I am flumoxed as a complete newbie in ror.  Any help would be greatly appreciated here.  I've back tracked using git and tried it again, but I get the same thing.  Thanks.

Frank

Comment: Maybe you will find some help [here](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails). Look at the different ways to setup your project with **Foundation**.

Comment: Thanks.   It seems like the foundation css is not being imported.  Even though I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and modifying the `Gemfile.lock` solved the problem.
Specifically, I changed the version of `foundation-rails`, which was `6. etc` to `(5.5.3.2)`, resulting in `foundation-rails (5.5.3.2)`.
This was the same version as specified in the GitHub repository of the author.
https://github.com/RailsApps/learn-rails/blob/master/Gemfile.lock  (line61)

Hope it helps!